Remove pairwise identical elements between two vectors and remove combination of duplicates
I'm trying to find a (maybe more elegant/efficient) way to remove elements in two vectors that are identical on a pairwise basis and remove duplicates across the remaining elements independent of their pairwise order.
For example:
V1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D") 
V2 <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A") 

I would like now  to remove identical elements and duplicates in a way that I end up with
V1  V2
A   B
A   C
D   A

so that pairs like AA, BB, CC, but also duplicates like BA (duplicate of AB) are removed.
Additionally, it would be great, if the remaining pairs are sorted, but that's now not the primary objective and would only be a bonus:
V1  V2
A   B
A   C
A   D

I have tried creating a data.frame and then subsetting identical pairs and then removing duplicates like this:
df <- data.frame(V1, V2)
df <- unique(subset(df, df[1] != df[2]))
df <- df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, maybe in a one-liner?
EDIT: An additional question: Is there maybe a way of getting the result without creating a data.frame and instead using both vectors directly? The end-result can be anything, a data.frame, matrix or another vector.

So if "Z" appears in both streams at the same position it should be deleted entirely?

A two-liner would be: df <- data.frame(V1, V2); df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) & df[,1] != df[,2], ]

Seems like this was asked and answered a couple of years ago.

Try the code below
unique(
    subset(
        transform(
            df,
            V1 = pmin(V1, V2),
            V2 = pmax(V1, V2)
        ),
        V1 != V2
    )
)

which gives
  V1 V2
2  A  B
4  A  C
8  A  D


strSort <- function(x)
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")

f1 <- function(V1, V2) {
  v <- paste0(V1, V2)
  uv <- unique(strSort(v[!duplicated(v) & 
                           !substr(v,1,1)==substr(v,2,2)]))
  data.frame(V1=substr(uv,1,1), V2=substr(uv,2,2))
}

f1(V1, V2)


  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  A  C
3  A  D

